# What is the purpose of analytics and telemetry sample code in Alljoyn Working Group?

Tags: alljoyn

I've been trying to understand the purpose of the sample code given in Analytics and Telemetry WG.

I was able to run the sample application without any errors. However, I do not see any analytics being used. The output of sample_service is as follows :

```
AllJoyn Library version: v14.12.000.
AllJoyn Library build info: AllJoyn Library v14.12.000 (Built Mon Mar 16 10:55:04 UTC 2015 by tcs - Git: alljoyn branch: '(detached from v14.12-rc1)' tag: 'v14.12-rc1' (+0 changes) commit ref: 0d71b216bb3a3cadc615c3eda6f8200093c5e117).
up and running
Accepting join session request from :ogb1Tlqe.3 (opts.proximity=ff, opts.traffic=1, opts.transports=ff7f).
Session Joined SessionId = 2474780947
RequestCredentials for authenticating peer name :ogb1Tlqe.3 using mechanism ALLJOYN_ECDHE_PSK authCount 0
Authentication Complete ALLJOYN_ECDHE_PSK successful
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /xampp HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Content-type: application/x-protobuf
Content-Length: 226

* upload completely sent off: 226 out of 226 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Fri, 27 Mar 2015 06:17:20 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
< Location: http://localhost/xampp/
< Content-Length: 231
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://localhost/xampp/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

And that of the sample_client is :

```
> AllJoyn Library version: v14.12.000. AllJoyn Library build info:
> AllJoyn Library v14.12.000 (Built Mon Mar 16 10:55:04 UTC 2015 by tcs
> - Git: alljoyn branch: '(detached from v14.12-rc1)' tag: 'v14.12-rc1' (+0 changes) commit ref: 0d71b216bb3a3cadc615c3eda6f8200093c5e117).
> Waited 0 seconds for JoinSession completion. JoinSession SUCCESS
> (Session id=-1820186349). RequestCredentials for authenticating peer
> name :ogb1Tlqe.2 using mechanism ALLJOYN_ECDHE_PSK authCount 0
> Authentication Complete ALLJOYN_ECDHE_PSK successful SetVendorData
> success SetDeviceData success SubmitEvent success SubmitEvent success
> SubmitEvent success RequestDelivery success
```

Git Repo : https://git.allseenalliance.org/cgit/analytics-telemetry/analytics.git/

Please help me understand what this program intends to do.

Answer (score 1):

This has since been answered on the [mailing list](https://lists.allseenalliance.org/pipermail/allseen-analytics-telemetry/2015-April/000046.html).

> The AllJoyn AnalyticsEventAgent interface is intended to log analytics data from an IoT device to an analytics cloud service. The sample code includes a sample client and service. The service code posts data to the cloud using protocol buffers.